# .htaccess RewriteRule from folder to file, with exceptions

Tags: apache, .htaccess

If I have a rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /$1.asp [QSA]
```

I can redirect domain.com/test to domain.com/test.asp

But there may be exceptions where I have a folder called test. How can I override my own rule with exceptions in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead to create exceptions:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!test/)([a-z0-9-]+)$ /$1.asp [L,NC,QSA]
```

Now this rule will be skipped for any request URI that starts with `/test/`